# Docker-compose EACCESS error when spawning executable

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, docker-compose

I have a Dockerfile where I bring in some files and chmod some stuff. it's a node server that spawns an executable file.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl sudo
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs && \
apt-get install --yes build-essential
RUN apt-get install --yes npm

#VOLUME "/usr/local/app"

# Set up C++ dev env
RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
   apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib cmake wget -y  && \
   apt-get clean autoclean && \
   apt-get autoremove -y
   #wget -O /tmp/conan.deb -L https://github.com/conan-io/conan/releases/download/0.25.1/conan-ubuntu-64_0_25_1.deb && \
   #dpkg -i /tmp/conan.deb

#ADD ./scripts/cmake-build.sh /build.sh
#RUN chmod +x /build.sh
#RUN /build.sh


RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs sudo


RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/app
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY package.json /usr/local/app
RUN ["npm", "install"]
COPY . .


RUN echo "/usr/local/app/dm" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN echo "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN echo "/usr/local/lib64" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN ldconfig

EXPOSE 9090
RUN chmod +x dm/dm3
RUN ldd dm/dm3
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "dm/dm3"]
RUN ["chmod", "777", "policy"]
RUN ls -al .
CMD ["nodejs", "app.js"]
```

it works all fine but when I use docker-compose for the purpose of having an autoreload dev enviornment in docker, I get an EACCES error when spawning the executable process.

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm run start
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/local/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

I'm using nodemon to restart the server on changes, hence the volumes in the compose. woulds love to get that workflow up again.

Comment: removing the volumes in the docker compose stops the error, but the files are no longer observed by nodemon

Answer (score 1):

I think that you problem is how you wrote the docker-compose.yml file.

1. I think that the line command doesn't necessary because you
   especified how start the program in Dockerfile.
2. Could you try to run this lines?

```js
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: 
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile    
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/local/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

Otherwise, I think that the volumes property doesn't share /usr/app/node_modules. And I think that this is bad practice. You can run "npm install" in your Dockerfile

I hope that you could understand me =)

Comment: No luck. is there a way to do this nodemon setup without docker-compose?

Comment: @JeremyNelson Yes! You can write this lines in nodemon config file (nodemon.js):

`code
{
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [
    "typescript",
    ".git",
    ".idea",
    "data/*",
    "service_*/*",
    "npm-debug.log",
    "node_modules/**/node_modules"
  ],
  "verbose": true,
  "execMap": {
    "js_temp": "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 --trace-sync-io",
    "js": "node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229"
  },
  "ext": "js json hbs"
}
`
and run nodemon command

Comment: Thank you! this works and starts nodemon but I don't get the server restart i was looking for.

Comment: It looks like i'm setting permissions in the docker file then overwriting them with the docker-compose volumes? would you agree? is there a way to set up volumes in a different directory?

Comment: @JeremyNelson Yes! you can write some volumes.
First: I think that you can write this volume: ./:/usr/local/app/. With this line you copy your source into the docker container. 
Second: you need write "npm install" and "nodemon" commands in Dockerfile. Finnaly: you run docker-compose up --build